# React native to expo migration issue with ReactLocalization module

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have an existing React-native project which I'm trying to move to [expo](https://expo.io)

I have followed the steps described [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-get-my-existing-react-native-project-running-with-expo) to do this. I have complete all the steps in the article, yet when I start the project I run into the following error.

[image]

From my [research](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization/issues/61) what I understood is that, a `libReactNativeLocalization.a` file is missing from somewhere.

Here is the [library](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) I'm using for localization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Expo, you can't react-native-link custom native modules. You write just JavaScript (unless you eject, in which case you're in a roughly similar situation before you tried to convert to Expo).

The way you can do localization with Expo is to use these functions:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/sdk/util.html#expoutilgetcurrentlocaleasync

There isn't a way to use the native module you link to without ejecting unfortunately.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, I could not find any detailed documentation for localization in Expo. The one in the above URL, I had seen earlier - since there was not detailed documentation just skipped past it.

Comment: By ejecting do you mean removing the native module? What about the other modules I use? Do I need to remove them also? I use a few modules for tasks like playing audio, onboarding etc.